# how to plot the variation of feature

Tags: python, plot

I have dataset with 2 columns and I would like to show the variation of one feature according to the binary output value

data

```
id      Column1     output
1          15          0
2          80          1
3         120          1
4          20          0
...       ...         ...
```

I would like to drop a plot with python where x-axis contains values of Column1 and y-axis contains the percent of getting positive values.

I know already that the form of my plot have the form of exponontial function where when column1 has smaller numbers I will get more positive output then when it have long values

Answer (score 0):

exponential plot maybe need two list like this
try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x-axis points list
xL = [5,10,15,20,25,30]

# y-axis points list
yL = [100,50,25,12,10]

plt.plot(xL, yL)

plt.axis([0, 35, 0, 200])
plt.show()
```

Comment: no it will not work becouse i have data  of 20 000 sample and I need a method for getting the probability for each range

Comment: # if i understand you correctly you can use something like this, x for x in range(initialValue,endValue,periodValue)
xL = [x for x in range(5,300,5)]